# Unwanted vertical space before epigraph

Tags: epigraphs

I am using `\epigraph` at the beginning of a new page and it introduces an undesired vertical offset. I have tried using `\setlength{\beforeepigraphskip}{0cm}`, but it didn't work. Any idea of how can I force the epigraph to adjust to the upper limit of the page?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\beforeepigraphskip}{0cm}

\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{flushright}

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{7cm}

\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}

\epigraph{\textit{blablablabla}}{\footnotesize{More blabla}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\epigraph` command begins with `\vspace{\beforeepigraphskip}`

But any space added by `\vspace{..}` is deleted at the beginning of the page. (Only  `\vspace*` adds a space that is not deleted.)

There are several options to turn around  this feature.

**(1)** Perhaps the simplest way in this case is to neutralize the action of `\epigraphflush` using `\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{hfill}` .

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{showframe}  

\begin{document}

    \renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{hfill}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{7cm}
    \setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
    
    \setlength{\beforeepigraphskip}{0cm}

    \epigraph{\textit{blablablabla}}{\footnotesize{More blabla}}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

**(2)** Using the command `\epigraphhead`. This is useful if want to print the epigraph before a chapter title.

The `\epigraphhead[<distance>]{<text>}` stores `text` for printing at `distance` below the header of the page. You will have to experiment with the `distance` value.

Some material on the page is needed for the command to print the stored text. An empty box will suffice for this example with an empty page.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    
    \renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{flushright}
    \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{7cm}
    \setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}  
    \setlength{\beforeepigraphskip}{0cm}    
    
    \epigraphhead[43]{\epigraph{\textit{blablablabla}}{\footnotesize{More blabla}}}
        
    \mbox{} % added     
\end{document}
```

**(3)**     Use `\epigraphhead[0]{...}` but now add a calculated `\beforeepigraphskip`.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    
    \renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{flushright}% flushright is the default
    \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{7cm}
    \setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}

    \setlength{\beforeepigraphskip}{\dimexpr 1in +\headheight}% changed <<<<<<<<<
        
    \epigraphhead[0]{\epigraph{\textit{blablablabla}}{\footnotesize{More blabla}}}
    
    \mbox{} % added 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! I settled for the first option. :)